# package ‘gdalUtils’ is not available for this version of R (4.2.0.)

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm trying to install `gdalUtils` in RStudio but it throws an error saying that a compatible version of it with my R v 4.2.0. (latest) does not exist. I need this package in order to use another. Any suggestions how to sole this?

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gdalUtils’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils/index.html says that it was removed (a few months ago) for not fixing errors in time, though I recognize that "corrected in time" is often subjective and likely pairs with complaints about timeliness of CRAN-related processes (I'm not slinging arrows). You can try `devtools::install_github("gearslaboratory/gdalUtils")`, and/or go to their [issues](https://github.com/gearslaboratory/gdalUtils) page to encourage updating their package, but no commits since Feb 2020 does not seem promising (supports CRAN's suggestion of unresponsive).

Comment: I understand. perhaps it has to do with the warnings that we should move away from using RGDAL in the future. Also, your offered code works! so thanks for that

Comment: Side note: if you're ever trying to install a package that has been archived from CRAN for some reason, and you are unable to find the _original_ github/gitlab repo (or another source-package location), one can often find the most-recent version on CRAN's repo page, as in https://github.com/cran/gdalUtils. It should support `devtools::install_github` in the same way, you're just using a snapshotted version, not necessarily live/dev. Again, just a hack until a more proper solution can be worked out. Glad my first comment got you moving forward.